# How to solve Python 3 package issues

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to install D-Wave's Python Library at https://cloud.dwavesys.com/leap/resources/developer-tools

I am using windows 10, and tried this using the command prompt and git bash.

They recommend a virtual environment, so I created one called ocean, activated it in Windows, and ran pip install dwave-ocean-sdk && dwave config create

I created a sample file called dwave.py with the following:

```
from dwave.cloud import Client

client = Client.from_config([TOKEN])
client.get_solvers()
```

but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dwave.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dwave.cloud import Client
  File "E:\work\local\research\dwave.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dwave.cloud import Client
ImportError: No module named 'dwave.cloud'; 'dwave' is not a package
```

I want to figure out how to solve this, but I am lost. I need some help debugging.

Comment: The easiest thing to try is to rename your sample file from `dwave.py` to something different than `dwave` as this could cause some problems due to naming your scripts similar to the library that you are using.

Comment: Umm, you solved it. Umm, two days of trying to figure this out by researching every known topic on Python packages and you solve it faster than Quantum computer. I can't tell you how stupid I feel right now. You are amazing. Thank you. P.S. Why don't you reply to this thread so I can give you credit for the answer.

Comment: Glad you solved it! No problem, I've been there too. Someone has already answered correctly, give him/her the credit so future readers will know how to solve it. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, you can't name your file using a **module/package name**. You have to re-name your file.

In my opinion, a file name has to explain what the program does in few words. If it is a test you can name it with `test_dwave.py` or something like that.

Cheers!